# On macOS, UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom returning .iPadOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

On macOS 12.4, when calling `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` from Mac Catalyst, it returns `.iPadOS` when the `Scale Interface to Match iPad` setting is enabled:

[image: Destinations]

However, if this setting is changed to "Optimize Interface for Mac," then `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` works correctly on macOS.

[image: Optimize for Mac]

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes it is. Please refer this post: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666451 and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/adapting-ios-code-to-run-in-the-macos-environment?preferredLanguage=occ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior from the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/adapting-ios-code-to-run-in-the-macos-environment?preferredLanguage=occ

> On macOS, the UITraitCollection and UIDevice classes report the following iOS idiom types instead of UIUserInterfaceIdiom.mac